# How can authentication be shared among multiple (sub-)domains?

Tags: api, sinatra, oauth-2.0, rack, warden

1. An unauthenticated user arrives at www.example.com.
2. The user logs in on: https://api.example.com/login
3. After successful login, the user is redirected to: https://dashboard.example.com
4. When going back to: www.example.com - the session is kept, and the user can now log out from there

An example is shown by Heroku, which shares cookies among the apps as in the screenshot.

[image: cookies from Heroku]

How does this setup work? 
How can this setup be imitated with Rack apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using SSO/OpenID  style techniques, for example by redirecting via forms and transmitting the authentication challenge tokens back and forth in the form parameters.

For example look how stackovervflow and sistersites do it. You can log into one using the other and it is implemented via forms and redirects.

For strictly subdomains, you can just use a single session cookie which is sent to all hosts within  "*.domain.com"

Comment: https://github.com/josh/rack-openid here seems to be a rackish implementation of openid integration. see how that works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137881/how-to-do-single-sign-on-among-multiple-sinatra-applications?rq=1  this might also help.

Comment: hmm... it looks like Heroku also uses some kind of openID, at least, there is 'nonce' in the URL after logout; so maybe I could do something with this:  https://github.com/openid/ruby-openid/blob/master/lib/openid/store/nonce.rb

Comment: possibly , anyways the problems and technologies are the same, so you can use that to research a solution which fits you. In this case the api.domain.com would be the SSO/openid/login server and the rest would use it to authenticate. In a corporate setting it might also keep a directory of user groups and access rights or roles.